# Validate File content in Bash Script

Tags: shell-script

I have a file (called `version`) that contains the text:

```
version=31
```

I want a `bash` script to check if the file contains: `version=31`. If it does, then continue with the script; if not, exit and present a message: `Image is not Image 31`.

How way I accomplish that?

Comment: Perhaps `grep`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is part of a larger script that iterates somehow over a number of image files with associated version files:

```
# image_fname: the filename of the image file
# image_version_fname: the filename of the image version info file
# image_version: an integer with the supposed version number

if ! grep -F -x -q "version=$image_version" "$image_version_fname"
then
  printf 'Warning: Image "%s" is not image %d\n' "$image_fname" "$image_version" >&2
  echo 'Warning: Version file contains:' >&2
  cat "$image_version_fname" >&2
fi
```

The flags to `grep` means "match as fixed string, not as regular expression" (`-F`), "match whole line" (`-x`) and "I'm just interested in the exit status, not in the matches themselves" (`-q`).

Comment: +1 for robustness and demonstration. Do avoid `fgrep`, using `-F` instead, as Kusalananda does. The man page says `Direct  invocation  as  either egrep or fgrep is deprecated, but is provided to allow historical applications that rely on them to run unmodified.`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
fgrep -xq 'version=31' version || { echo "Image is not Image 31"; exit 1; }
```

This `grep`s the file `version` for the string `version=31`, and if it doesn't find the string it displays the message and exits. If it does find the string the script will continue.

If you anticipate the version changing, you'd probably want to replace `version=31` with a variable:

```
imgver="version=31"
fgrep -xq "$imgver" version || { echo "Image is not Image $imgver"; exit 1; }
```

Comment: This will pass `version=310helloworld` as valid too. Add `-x` to `grep -F` to fix that.

Comment: Thanks both, good catches. I had single quotes round the var as well... :/

Comment: There are still syntax errors (test your command, you'll see). The syntax I gave you is ok afaik. And, as suggested by Kusalananda, `grep -F` is more portable than `fgrep`.